# How to do pagination in recycler view which is in fragment in android studio?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, pagination, retrofit

I want to do pagination in recycler view which is used in fragment, where the response for recycler view is coming from api.

I have searched a lot but could not understand anything.

The response comes like this but in 100's:

```
[{
    "Full_name": "matariya angel jigneshbhai",
    "date": "2020-10-13 12:49:01"
},
{
    "Full_name": "Jeesh Jigneshbhai mangukiya",
     "date": "2020-10-13 10:55:50"
}]
```

Dance Fragment:

```
public class DanceFragment extends Fragment {
Unbinder unbinder;


@BindView(R.id.rvDanceFragment)
RecyclerView rvDanceFragment;
@BindView(R.id.rvDanceFragment1)
RecyclerView rvDanceFragment1;
@BindView(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar progressBar;
@BindView(R.id.nestedSV)
NestedScrollView nestedSV;
@BindView(R.id.coordinatorLout)
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLout;


public static final String TAG2 = "DANCE2 TAG";
Dance2Adapter dance2Adapter;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  
    getAllDance2Posts();


}


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dance, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}



public void getAllDance2Posts() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Call<List<Dance2>> ourSupplierResponseCall = RestClient.getClient().getDance2Posts();
    ourSupplierResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Dance2>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Dance2>> call, Response<List<Dance2>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d(TAG2, "On Dance2 Response: " + response.toString());

                generateDataList2(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Dance2>> call, Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}


private void generateDataList2(List<Dance2> danceList2) {

    dance2Adapter = new Dance2Adapter(danceList2, getContext());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvDanceFragment1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rvDanceFragment1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvDanceFragment1.setAdapter(dance2Adapter);
    rvDanceFragment1.smoothScrollBy(0, 1);
    rvDanceFragment1.smoothScrollBy(0, -1);

}}
```

I think adapter also need some changes to identify the items coming from response.

Adapter  code:

```
public class Dance2Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Dance2Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Dance2>  dance2List;
Context context;
boolean isLiked;

public Dance2Adapter(List<Dance2> dance2List, Context context) {
    this.dance2List = dance2List;

    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_feed_post, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.txtUserName.setText(dance2List.get(position).getFullName());

    String dt_txt = dance2List.get(position).getDate();
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = fmt.parse(dt_txt);

        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy, hh:mm aa");
        String newFormat = fmtOut.format(date);

        holder.txtPostTime.setText(newFormat);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dance2List.size();
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    
    TextView txtUserName,  txtPostTime;
    


    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
      

        txtUserName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        txtPostTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostTime);

    } }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's better to use [paging3](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) see this [sample](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#0)

Answer (score 0):

You can either make a BaseRecyclerViewAdapter or make your own adapter extend RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
  super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

  RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
  RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();

  if (layoutManager.getChildCount() > 0) {
    int lastItemIndex = layoutManager.getChildCount() -1;
    View lastItemVisibleView = layoutManager.getChildAt(lastItemIndex);
    int adapterPosition = layoutManager.getPosition(lastItemVisibleView);
    boolean isLastItemVisible = (adapterPosition == adapter.getItemCount() -1);

    if (isLastItemVisible)
      // Implement interface method to call the data fetch  
  }
}
```

In the above code we first take the index of the last item (as index start from 0, last index will be 1 less than the total items in the list).
We then just check if the last item is actually visible, by comparing the position at which the adapter currently is.